# What’s the duration of the winds of Flaywind Burst?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

The spell Flaywind Burst (from *Sandstorm*) says the following:

> This spell produces a brief windstorm (approximately 70 mph), filled with scouring, supernatural grit that literally strips flesh [...] A creature within the area of flaywind burst must make a Fortitude save or experience the effects of the wind's force [...] Large or Huge creatures are unable to move forward against the force of the blast, or if flying are blown back 1d6×5 feet.

Since the spell is Instantaneous yet has a full round casting time, how long & when does the wind affect the creatures of size large? Would they be unaffected on their turn, the spell essentially doing nothing but damage vs. large or larger creatures, or does it affect them in some way?

> #### Flaywind Burst
>
> Casting Time: 1 round
> Range: 60 ft.
> Area: Cone-shaped burst
> Duration: Instantaneous

Answer (score 1):

## That's an accurate reading of *flaywind burst*

Unlike, for example, the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*gust of wind*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsFtoG.html#gust-of-wind) [evoc] (*Player's Handbook* 238) that has a duration of 1 round, the 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell ***flaywind burst*** [evoc] (*Sandstorm* 115) has a [duration](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#duration) of instantaneous, and that means, once the spell's effect is resolved, the spell's effect ends, leaving, in this case, only devastation in its wake—dealing its not insignificant damage, tossing about littler foes, and scaring the crap out of terriers carried in picnic baskets by Kansas girls.

The spell likely mentions how "Large or Huge creatures [that aren't flying] are unable to move forward against the force of the blast" because that *is*—technically—the effect of a windstorm-strength wind (as seen [here](http://dndsrd.net/wildernessAndEnvironment.html#table-wind-effects)). Your feeling is correct, though, that it would likely take a *monumentally* convoluted ready action for a Large or Huge walking creature to ever be checked by the effect of a *flaywind burst* spell, especially considering its excessive 1-round casting time (that, by the way, is—sadly and confusingly—different from a full-round casting time; more [here](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#casting-time)).

So, yes, the *flaywind burst* spell typically won't prevent Large and Huge nonflying foes from approaching, the spell's effect having ended as quickly as it began therefore leaving those who had been affected by it—if they survived—capable of, afterward, approaching the caster normally.